# How to control the content (text) to display in a $form->input?

Tags: php, cakephp

folks.
I'm starting with CakePHP and after reviewing this tutorial (
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application
)  and also after having  used the "cake bake" command to generate my
models,
controllers and views , everything is fine, but when I visit the
Post's add view (views \ posts
\ add.php), I find that instead of showing a input text for the
username, it shows a select with all the usernames.

this is the line in  the Post's add view that show the select.

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
```

**PostsController** :

```
function add() {
// Some other code  
    $users = $this->Post->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

Although I know how to display only the username of the currently
logged-in user,  I don't know how to control the content to show in
$this->Form->input()  because if I use a variable that is not part of
the "Post" model , it's shown , but as the label for the input.

Have you any idea how to solve this??

P.S. I've been trying to find this information on the cookbook , but I haven't been able to find anything specific to my situation :(

Comment: If there is a variable called `user_id` in your controller being passed to your view and it is an array of users, cakephp will automatically generate a select box from that. Also, shouldn't `user_id` be the id of the user, not the username?

Comment: @Corey- you're right,there is an array of users ($users), but I'm afraid I haven't explained myself well, what I'd like to know is if it's possible to display a constant string using input()? because every-time I try to do this, the string is displayed, but as a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a string in as the value of the input, try this :

```
echo $form->input('my label text',array('value'=>'the value string','type'=>'hidden'));
```

That would make the input hidden, and set the value.
Or remove the `type=>hidden` and it will have a value, you can also add things like `disabled` and such in there, or to modify the `div` it creates, use `div'=>array()` and put your `div` options in that array... hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

i would like to help you on this thing.

first of all when you want a text box then you must define the type of the input field.

```
echo $form->input('user_id', array('type'=>'text', 'label'=false));
```

i hope this will help you.